# How to prevent key UP & DOWN behavior in HTML Input Fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are similar questions on stackoverflow, but 
none of them I think has working solution. So when you type key UP or Down when you have focus on an HTML input field, the cursor automatically moves to the front/end of the input value.

(You can check this with the Top-right Search box on the stackoverflow site).

I want to remove this!!

I tried the following code, but didn't work:

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#input_field", function(event) {
    if(event.which==38 || event.which==40){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Any solution for this..?

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra I'm writing a browser game that makes use of the arrow keys. Preventing the default browser behaviour is crucial... for example.

Comment: Did the answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 7):

I don't see the point in preventing a fairly useful behavior, but this works for me with the SO search box:

```
$(document).on("keydown keyup", "#search input", function(event) { 
    if(event.which==38 || event.which==40){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This code targets both `keyup` and `keydown` events.

Comment: when you type and a dropdown with suggestions appears you can use `keyup` and `keydown` to navigate the suggestions. So in this case you don't want the cursor to move to the start/end

Comment: This answer provides the exact code given in the question. It also does not work.

Comment: @IanS, this is not the exact code as in the question, but rather adds 2 event listeners, to both `keydown` and `keyup`. It works on StackOverflow in both Chrome and Firefox (actually, the original code works now as well, as long as the selector targets the `input` field), I think that it did not work in the version that was current when the answer was written, which may have required adding the `keyup` listener. If you could specify your test details or post a question with them, I or someone else may be able to assist.

Comment: My apologies for not seeing keyup. I was more meaning event.preventDefault(); My code is the same only using Vue.js directives to listen to the keyup and keydown functions